# bash - pass by value with no correct result

Tags: bash, pass-by-value

My code is the following:

```
vpnname="test vpn"
    
booleanCheck(){
    echo $1
    if (statement) then
       sendMail $1
    }
    
    sendMail(){
    mailsubject = "subject test for - $1" 
}
    
if ! ping 8.8.8.8 then
then 
    checkIfSendEmail "$@$vpnname"
fi
```

my value of the second last line passes greatly to `booleanCheck()` but once it gets to `sendMail()`, the value gets lost.
what am i doing wrong?

i tried showing it by `"$1"` or `'$1'` or `$@$1` o `${1}` in the function `sendMail()` without a result

Comment: your code doesn't look tidy, for example what's to do with your double `then` and missing `fi`? And are you expecting `ping` to exit on its own?

Comment: they are only snippets to be sure i'm only showing the most important

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wrap *all* your variables in double quotes *while passing* so any spaces in between won't get split:

```
booleanCheck(){
    echo "$1"
    if (statement) then
        sendMail "$1"
    fi
}
```

Recommended: Use [shellcheck](https://www.shellcheck.net/) to eliminate these obvious bad practices.